# How to pass predicate to function in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, predicate

I have :

```
 public void InitializeStatusList(DropDownList list)
    {
       var dictionaryEntries = GetEntriesFromDatabase();
       list.DataSource = dictionaryEntries.Where(entry => entry is EntryStatus1 || entry is EntryStatus2);
       list.DataBind();           
    }
```

I have many of these functions. I want to write common function with `dictionaryEntries` query condition passed as predicate.

For example:

```
public void InitializeStatusList(DropDownList list)
{
    CommonInitializeStatusList(DropDownList list, entry => entry is EntryStatus1 || entry is EntryStatus2);
}

public void CommonInitializeStatusList(DropDownList list, ??????????????? predicate)
{                       
    var dictionaryEntries = GetEntriesFromDatabase();
    list.DataSource = dictionaryEntries.Where(predicate);
    list.DataBind();        
}
```

What stands for `???????????????`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @reinierpost, I've just fixed `initialize` typo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Func<Entry, bool> predicate` should work, where `Entry` is type of `entry` variable.

Comment: what is the namespace/library to include for this Entry class?

Comment: @thanatorr - Entry is custom Enum.

Comment: @MichałKuliński yes, I figured that out by now, thank you though!

Answer (score 8):

You can do like this:

```
public void InitializeStatusList(DropDownList list)
{    
    Func<Entry,bool> predicate=entry=>entry is EntryStatus1 || entry is EntryStatus2;
    CommonInitializeStatusList(list, predicate);
}

public void CommonInitializeStatusList(DropDownList list, Func<Entry,bool> predicate)
{                                 
    var dictionaryEntries = GetEntriesFromDatabase();    
    list.DataSource = dictionaryEntries.Where(predicate);
    list.DataBind();

}
```